# detecting scroll event on top of a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an iframe with scrolling displaying a document. I also have a canvas on top covering about 90% of the document so I can draw stuff on there.

```
<iframe id='commentingFrame'  frameborder='0' class='pageFrame' src='document' ></iframe>
<canvas id="drawLineCanvas" class='drawingCanvas' width="1400" height="900" ></canvas>

iframe.pageFrame{
    width:70%;
    height:700px;
    border:1px;
    float:left;
    overflow: scroll;
    z-index: 0;  
    position:absolute;
}

drawingCanvas{
    position:absolute; 
    z-index: 1; 
   pointer-events:none;
}
```

The issue is when my mouse is over the iframe, I would like to use scrolling with mouse wheel. However, I am assuming since the canvas is top, scrolling for my iframe is not working and instead the main window is being scrolled. Is there a way to add on scroll event listener to the canvas? Is there a better way to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: What if you had a button, or a hotkey, so when users press this it toggles the z-index of the iframe and the canvas, because currently, as you stated, the canvas is on top of the iframe which is preventing you from interacting with it

Comment: I actually need the canvas to be on top so user can click on it to add points to it .